# Does the COVID-19-related automated visa extension till the 30th of April 2020 in Thailand also apply to foreigners who entered Thailand visa-free?

Tags: visas, thailand, visa-free-entry, covid-19, visa-extensions

I read on https://immigration.go.th/content/visa_auto_extension ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200408192249/https://immigration.go.th/content/visa_auto_extension)):

> ‍♂️ The person whose visas has expired from 26th of March 2020 will be automatically extended to 30th of April 2020. There is no need to apply for a visa extension at Immigration Office for this period and will not be fined THB 500 per day for this case.

Does the COVID-19-related automated visa extension till the 30th of April 2020 also apply to foreigners who [entered Thailand visa-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_Thailand&oldid=945397026#30_days_exemption_(51_nations))?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNrRaM)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thailand/comments/fanxyb/covid19_megathread_for_rthailand/fmtk6ib/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Update (2020-04-21)](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1160719-thailand-extends-foreigners-visas-for-a-second-time-as-coronavirus-cases-slow/) ([mirror](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1160719-thailand-extends-foreigners-visas-for-a-second-time-as-coronavirus-cases-slow/)):

> Foreigners whose visas had expired since March 26 will be **permitted to stay until July 31 without having to apply for an extension**, said Narumon Pinyosinwat, spokeswoman for the Thai government.

Official source: https://www.thaigov.go.th/news/contents/details/29468  ([mirror](https://archive.vn/wip/yKGXH)).

---

Yes, according to the following sources.

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-thailand-cases-idUSKBN21Q0GD:

> Those foreigners who entered the country before the ban was imposed - who had visas, received visas on arrival or under **visa waiver programmes** - will not need to line up at often crowded immigration centres around the country to extend their stay.
>
> The automatic visa extension has been granted until April 30, according to an interior ministry document. Police Lieutenant General Sompong Chingduang told Reuters the government could extend this deadline each month.

https://immigration.go.th/content/visa_auto_extension (now updated with English version of the image):

[image]

Unofficial translation of the official "Notification  of the  Ministry of Interior" on the "Permission  for  Certain  Groups  of  Aliens  to  Remain  in  the  Kingdom  as  a  Special  Case" from http://mfa.go.th/main/contents/files/news3-20200410-172909-334229.pdf:

[image]

[image]