# Does the 30-day extension of one's stay start from 30th of April 2020 (COVID-19-related automated stay extension) or from 30 days after entry to THA?

Tags: visas, thailand, visa-free-entry, covid-19, visa-extensions

When extending one's stay after entering Thailand as a French citizen via the [visa waiver programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_Thailand&oldid=945397026#30_days_exemption_(51_nations)) and after benefiting from [the COVID-19-related automated stay extension till the 30th of April 2020](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156594/1810), does the regular, manual, 1900-THB, non-covid-related [30-day extension](http://www.asiatraveltips.com/news14/288-ThailandVisa.shtml) start from 30th of April 2020 or from 30 days after entry to Thailand?

---

The question can be rephrased via the following example:

1. Robert arrived in Thailand on March 15 with the visa waiver programme.
2. On  April 30, 2020, Robert  applies for a [30-day extension](http://www.asiatraveltips.com/news14/288-ThailandVisa.shtml) (regular, manual, 1900-THB, not covid-related extension).

Will Robert be allowed stay in Thailand till ~May 15, 2020 or ~May 30, 2020?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNry6Q)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/g021no)
- [thaivisa.com](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1159424-does-the-30-day-extension-of-ones-stay-start-from-30th-of-april-2020-covid-19-related-automated-stay-extension-or-from-30-days-after-visa-free-entry-to-thailand/)

and someone else posted the same question on the [Facebook public group "Thai visa advice"](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1395920320731833/permalink/2723984461258739/).

Nobody knows.

Comment: The order cited in the other question states that the extension is _to_ 30 April, not _from_ 30 April.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, I'm curious what happens if an individual applies to the "manual" [30-day extension](http://www.asiatraveltips.com/news14/288-ThailandVisa.shtml). Will the "manual" 30-day extension  start from 30th of April 2020 or from 30 days after entry to Thailand?

Answer (score 2):

The Thai government text from [your own previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156594/does-the-covid-19-related-automated-visa-extension-till-the-30th-of-april-2020-i) provides the answer to this query. The Thai Immigration Bureau's English text says:

*Aliens permitted to stay in the Kingdom according to visa category and visa exemption whose permitted length of stay has expired since March 26, 2020 onwards.*

*The length of stay permit will be automatically extended to April 30, 2020, without the need to file for a visa extension.*

Confusion arises because the press (and the Thai government) have referred to this extension as a "30-day extension." The text presented, however, indicates that the extension period is not a "30-day" extension, and is not figured by counting 30-days from another date or occurrence.

Instead, time is added to qualifying persons' entry permission (both visa and non-visa entries) so that they may remain in Thailand until April 30, 2020 without further application for a visa extension.

To remain legally past April 30, 2020, would therefore require a formal visa  or non-visa entry extension to be granted by the government. The notice text suggests a visa holder may apply for an exception, but does not address whether a non-visa entrant may secure an extension of their entry permission.

Comment: Thanks, the question can be rephrased via the following example: Robert arrived in Thailand on March 15 with the visa waiver programme, and on  April 30, 2020 applies for a [30-day extension](http://www.asiatraveltips.com/news14/288-ThailandVisa.shtml) (typical extension, not covid-related): will Robert be allowed stay in Thailand till ~May 15, 2020 or ~May 30, 2020?

Comment: The Notice cited in your comment says the extension is for "30 additional days." That suggests (but not dispositively) that the answer is "30 days past the day the traveler was to leave under the traveler's first entry." Thus, if under his first entry Robert were able to say in Thailand until March 15, which date was then administratively extended to April 30, then if Robert's later visa extension was granted for 30 additional days, he would have to depart May 30.

Comment: Thanks, according to the notice, I agree with you, but I don't know whether the wording was chosen carefully, and it is not an official document, so I still have some doubts.

Comment: Me too: note my use of the words "not dispositive."

Comment: Thanks, good point I had indeed missed it, I appreciate your experience as an attorney :)

Comment: You're welcome, Franck. Hope it's all helpful.